# Show Groupnames in a dropdown list

Tags: python, django

I am working on a studentresult website in Python and Django. Now I want to ask to the database to give me the names of the groups that are in the database. Using the standard db.sqlite3 database from django. In the Dropdown menu I get three white bars because I have three groups now. When I the Class DisplayGroups to id = Models.IntegerField(id, flat=True) change return.self.group_name to return self.id then the dropdownlist shows me the ID that the group has. But how can I show the name of the group. Tried a lot:

- Changed to group in the model
- Changed to groupname in the model
- Changed a few of the commands in the views.py
- Made a new database item Groepen and changed query to that.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import DisplayGroups, DisplayUsername
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

def index(request):
    response = redirect('/login')
    return response


def home(response):
    return render(response, "home/home.html")


def bekijk(request):
    DisplayGroup = Group.objects.all()
    print(DisplayGroup)
    DisplayNames = User.objects.all()
    print(DisplayNames)
    return render(request, "home/bekijk.html", {"DisplayGroups": DisplayGroup,"DisplayUsername":DisplayNames})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class DisplayGroups(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class DisplayUsername(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**The html page**

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Cijfers studenten{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $productvar=$("#groupdd1");
            $itemvar=$("#userdd1");

            $options=$itemvar.find('option');
            $productvar.on('change', function()
            {
                $itemvar.html($options.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'))
            }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Studentresultaten</h1>
<select id="groupdd1">
    <option disabled="true" selected>-- Select Fruit --</option>
    {% for result in DisplayGroups %}
    <option>{{result.group_name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="userdd1">
    <option disabled="true" selected>-- Select Fruit --</option>
    {% for result in DisplayUsername %}
    <option>{{result.username}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endblock %}
```

The piece of jquery is for later, because I want to make a dependant dropdown menu. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You make a query `DisplayGroup = Group.objects.all()`, but your model is `DisplayGroups`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem when I change the query to `DisplayGroups = Group.objects.all()` then the dropdown still shows three entries, but all blank. The strings are not shown.

Comment: of course, since a `Group` has no `group_name` field, so `{{ result.group_name }}` makes no sense.

Comment: But it has a name, in this case **test**. Is it possible to show that name inside the dropdown menu, or is it not possible to do that?

Comment: just use `{{ result }}`. Then it will call the `str(..)`, on the group, or you can use `{{ result.name }}`.

Answer (score 0):

@WilliamVanOnsem is right the model from where you are filtering is Group which do not have group_name as a field. Here's what you can do.
In views.py

```
DisplayGroup = DisplayGroups.objects.all()
DisplayNames = DisplayName.objects.all()
```

Now in HTML template you can access group_name and result.username. The User model has username field so result.username did not show an empty text